# Create an custom installer that downloads multiple files sequentially on Mac?

Tags: macos, shell, scripting, installation

I'm trying to create an installer that does the following:

1. Download an unzip a large zip file from s3
2. Download a dynamically generated config file from my server
3. Unzip the config file and patch it to the original file from s3
4. Execute a specific file from the resulting directory

I am a newbie to this so I have no idea where to start. So far I can just imagine doing this as a shell script (but not even sure it's a viable option, or if there's a better way to do this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at homebrew http://brew.sh/ and homebrew cask https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask

there maybe something suitable for you.

Use bash scripts to perform the operations that is what it is used for ... curl to download the files, zip to uncompress the files and cp to copy the files or whatever you use on the CLI to execute the tasks or have a look at using python. the pseudo code would be something like this:

```
curl mys3account/myfile.zip 
zip extract myfile.zip to foo_dir 
curl localserver/mygenconfig.zip 
zip extract mygenconfig.zip to foo_dir run foo_dir/myappe
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't mean to be unappreciative but brew is the last thing I would want to do this. Personally I've had nothing but bad experiences with brew, seriously majority of the times it has some dependency errors that causes a simple brew command to fail. Also, I'm looking for something that works natively out of the box. Not yet another package manager I need to install. It should just be a single click and do its job. Any ideas?

Comment: Use bash scripts to perform the operations that is what it is used for ...   curl to download the files, zip to uncompress the files and cp to copy the files or whatever you use on the CLI to execute the tasks or have a look at using python.

the pseudo code would be something like this:

'curl mys3account/myfile.zip
zip extract myfile.zip to foo_dir
curl localserver/mygenconfig.zip
zip extract mygenconfig.zip to foo_dir
run  foo_dir/myapp'

Comment: Thanks, that's actually what I ended up doing, and it works! Could you update the answer to add the shell method? I will accept the answer.